# Roll out Check-In Policies to Multiple Machines

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need to add some Check-In policies to a bunch of machines.  When I go to Project Settings -> Source Control I can get into the options fine, but I know I have higher permissions than most, but when I try to add them on other developers machines I get an access denied message.

Is there a way that I can roll out check-in policies to all machines and have the client "install" the policy regardless of permissions?  I don't want to grant people higher access and then have to take it away.

Also, with access to Source Control settings being denied would this still run the policy as expected?

Edit: I have read that TFS Power Tools has this ability.  If people are part of the same team / group, how does it automatically download the files?  Or does the developer have to do a Get Latest?  Source: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/12/04/distributing-visual-studio-addin-for-the-team/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to have a DLL in a single location and roll out the registry keys via a batch file.